# Prestashop get product attributes from its id

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop I want to get product's all attribute from its product id. Lets say I have a product with id as 3. Now from product id 3 I want to get all of its attribute like name, price, stock, category, product link.. etc.

So far I have tried

```
$product_id = $result['id_product'];
$id_product = (int)$product_id;
$product = new Product(Tools::getValue($id_product));
var_dump($product);
```

But its giving me an array with all attributes in blank. The array can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=bgG34h7a)

So can someone tell me how to get its all attribute from id? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one obvious mistake is

```
Tools::getValue($id_product)
```

Which is basically

```
$_GET[$id_product]
```

So in your case that would probably evaluate to

```
$product = new Product($_GET['3']);
```

So remove `Tools::getValue` and try again:

```
$product_id = $result['id_product'];
$id_product = (int)$product_id;
$product = new Product($id_product);
var_dump($product);
```

Answer (score 3):

or you can safe some lines, which is more simple:

```
$product = new Product( (int)$result['id_product']);
var_dump($product);
```

Good luck!